# How to check if clangd is running in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clangd

I installed `clangd`, but I'm not sure if it's running. I don't seem to be getting some of the features that were advertised, so I feel like it's not running or only partially working.

I'm looking at the "Visual Studio Code" section of https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clangd/Installation.html.

Here it says:

> Debug logs: when clangd is running, you should see “Clang Language Server” in the dropdown of the Output panel (View -> Output).

In my drop down (see image below), I only see `clangd` but there is no `Clang language server`. Are these 2 equivalent? If not, then it appears that `clangd` isn't running properly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is running. The output panel was renamed to "clangd" at some point in the VSCode extension.